# Proving that $-\frac{\cos x +\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{(1 + \cos x)^2} = -\frac{1}{1 + \cos x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could anyone give me some details on how this happens?

$$-\frac{\cos x +\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x}{(1 + \cos x)^2} = -\frac{1}{1 + \cos x}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$-\frac{\cos x + \overbrace{\cos^2 x+ \sin^2 x}^{=1}}{(1+\cos x)^2} = -\frac{\cos x + 1}{(1+\cos x)^2} = -\frac{1}{1+\cos x} $$